# How to connect mongodb to the application server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have 2 ec2 instances running one for **application** and other for **mongodb**,

I have set up the mongodb instance as follows:

1.)Installed docker

2.)`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb -v ~/data:/data/db mongo`

3.)Container created, checked `mongod` services are started.

4.) connected to it with the mongo, `docker run -it --link mongodb:mongo --rm mongo sh -c 'exec mongo "$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR:$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/mydatabase"'`

After executing the above command mongod shell is started where I found the uri as `mongod://xx.xxx.xx.xx:27017/mydatabase`

5.)I have checked my ec2 instace ip:27017 which connects me to mongodb.

**Question1**: I want to connect it to my application server which is running on different ec2 instance, so I have provided the uri in the config file which is present above, `mongod://xx.xxx.xx.xx:27017/mydatabase` but when connecting to app-server I am getting the 502 bad gateway error.

How do I connect this? Is the process correct?

Comment: there can be multiple issues here like firewall settings etc. Try pinging your mongodb instance from application server and check its pingable?

Comment: okay,my problem gets fixed.

Comment: what was the solution ?

Comment: I have not build the new image, of the server when updating the url, previously i was using the wrong url.